# Portable message box buttons/icons?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, multiplatform

I'm trying to create a portable message box API (as part of a bigger API that requires the usage of message boxes). At the moment, I'm developing it with Windows but I want to port it to Linux later on. I'm wondering if it's a bad idea to include all of the of message box icons/buttons the Win32 API has. Are there equivalents to them on other platforms? Is there a good portable subset I could use?

Answer (score 0):

[Non-Native UI Sucks](http://blog.codinghorror.com/non-native-ui-sucks/)

So just wrap the native messagebox in a portable messagebox class/function could do the job.